# Dataset of planets and moons in the solar system

Tags: data-request, astronomy

Where can I find such dataset.

For each object, I would want name, size, distance from sun (if applicable), mass. Can be separate dataset for all moons and for all planets. (and maybe asteroids).

Comment: You *can* get all this from Wikipedia. Start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet

Comment: "and maybe asteroids" is a much, much larger scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Devstronomy](https://devstronomy.martinovo.net/) project provides the [datasets](https://devstronomy.martinovo.net/#/datasets) for planets (plus Pluto) and their satellites(moons) in accessible formats (CSV, JSON, SQL), available for download. The datasets originate from the NASA Jet Propulsion Laboratory. Check the site for details.

**Edit**: please note that I'm the author of the Devstonomy project. I had a similar issue and did not find a solution. So I've provided the datasets on the Devstronomy site.

Comment: @NisseEngström: Thanks for correcting me, Nisse. This was my first answer here. It makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 4):

These two put everything in one place and so are simple.

[FindTheData](http://planets.findthedata.com/)
[Windows2Universe](http://www.windows2universe.org/our_solar_system/planets_table.html)

This one treats each astronomical object separately, but you can get much more detailed information.

[NASA](https://pds.nasa.gov/tools/data-search/)